# In benzyne intermiediate of anisole why -I effect of OCH3 is considered not +M effect of it?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

[image]

Here they considered -I effect of $\ce{OCH3}$ so carboanion is stable at orthroposition;

But $\ce{OCH3}$ also shows $\text{+M}$ effect if $\text{+M}$ is shown carboanion will be stable at meta position(generally in substitution reaction we give preference to $\text{+M > -I}$ of $\ce{OCH3}$).

**But for this reaction NH2 in orthro position is not at all formed.**

**What is exactly happening in this reaction?**

Comment: carbon already has 8 valence electrons, so -och3 won't donate anymore electrons through +M (since resonance is impossible), we only consider -I here

Comment: @Naren I think one explanation is that the carbanion is in the plane of the ring (in an sp2 orbital) while the delocalisation (+M effect) only occurs via p-orbitals perpendicular to the plane of the ring. So, the resonance does not affect the anion.